# Tengo problemas para desinstalar el gestor de Kubernetes de Linux: kubectl

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kubernetes

tengo linux en WSL (estoy usando windows), recientemente instale Kubectl pero ahora quiero desinstalarlo con el siguiente comando kubectl delete all --all pero me aparece el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agradezco mucho si me pueden ayudar a desinstalar Kubernetes, he mirado en diferentes sitios información pero hasta ahora no he podido :/

Comment: Para poder desinstalarlo debes tener el servicio arrancado. Tu mensaje de error muestra que la conexión fue rechazada, por lo que tiene toda la pinta de que está parado. ¿Qué distribución has usado en WSL para instalar Kubernetes? Debes usar `systemctl start` y el nombre del servicio para arrancarlo, después de eso podrás hacer uso de esa instrucción.

Comment: Estoy usando Ubuntu la version 22.04, cual sería el nombre del servicio amigo? porque es que yo solo lo he instalado pero no lo he utilizado, y pues ahora quiero desinstalarlo.  La verdad tampoco entiendo porque intenta hacerme esa conexión en el puerto 8080 al ejecutar ese comando

Comment: Toda la funcionalidad de Kubernetes, como su gestión, se exporta a través de un API REST a través de un servidor web interno. Por lo que me dices parece que lo que deseas es empezar de cero o eliminar la máquina virtual de Ubuntu 20.04. Estoy en tránsito, a mi llegada te explico cómo arrancar el servicio y a reinstalar/borrar la máquina virtual.

Comment: Si es que necesito desinstalarlo por un problema que tengo en el pc, pero entonces no quiero desinstalar el Ubuntu sino que solo el Kubetcl

Comment: Disculpa la tardanza, se me complicó la mañana de trabajo. ¿Puedes probar a arrancar el servicio usando `systemctl start kubelet`?. Tras eso prueba a desinstalar de nuevo.

Comment: Tranquilo compa, cuando puedas responder no hay problem. Mira me salio este error: "System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate. Failed to connect to bus: Host is down"....Para que sirve este comando?

Comment: Disculpa, olvidé el problema de `systemctl` en WSL. Prueba con `service kubelet start`.

Comment: Hola disculpa por la demora, que raro me salió este error al ejecutar tu comando: " kubelet: unrecognized service"...... osea parece que no reconoce el comando

Comment: Creo que sería mejor desinstalar los paquetes de Kubernetes o, mejor aún, que reinstales la máquina de Ubuntu 20.04 en vez de tratar de desinstalar Kubernetes. ¿Tienes datos o cosas en esa máquina virtual que desees mantener? ¿O solo quieres mantenerla para usarla para otras cosas?

Comment: Si me gustaría desinstalar Ubuntu 22.04 (tengo esa versión) del WSL, y volverlo a instalar, la verdad no tengo archivos que quiera mantener, sabes como podría reinstalar el Ubuntu bro?

Comment: Ya te has respondido con las instrucciones para eliminar la distribución (de me han adelantado). Faltarían las instrucciones para volver a instalarla.

Comment: Cuidado `kubelet` es el gestor de un nodo de K8s.  Nada que ver con el binario ejecutable para gestionar un cluster de K8s.

Comment: Una última duda para redactar una respuesta que cubra todos los frentes. ¿De dónde seguiste las instrucciones para instalar Kubernetes en tu Ubuntu 20.04? ¿Es una instalación MicroK8s, Charmed Kubernetes o Kubernetes desde los repositorios de Google?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Kubectl` es la herramienta para administrar un clúster de K8s. No es ni un clúster ni un nodo K8s. És un fichero binario executable.

Solamente tienes que borrar el ejecutable del directorio donde se encuentre, o via `APT` si lo has hecho desde gestor de paquetes

Localiza el binario:

```
gil@k8s:~$ whereis kubectl
kubectl: /usr/bin/kubectl
```

Eliminalo con usuario con permisos

```
sudo rm /usr/bin/kubectl
```

Caso que lo hayas instalado con `APT` :

```
gil@k8s:~$ sudo apt remove kubectl
```

Si no lo sabes, puedes consultar la base de datos:

```
gil@k8s:~$ sudo dpkg -l | grep kubectl
ii  kubectl                               1.24.3-00                               amd64        Kubernetes Command Line Tool
```

En mi caso, si lo instale con la ayuda de `APT`

Suerte!

Comment: Excelente respuesta, encaminada a resolver la duda original en vez de los comentarios.

Answer (score 0):

Para eliminar completamente la distribución, **perdiendo todos los datos que tienes en ella**, sigue estos pasos:

Abre una ventana de PowerShell y teclea el siguiente comando para listar las distribuciones instaladas:

```
wsl -l
```

Te va a aparecer la lista de distribuciones,por ejemplo:

```
NAME          STATE
NombreDistro  Running
```

En lugar de `NombreDistro` probablemente diga `Ubuntu`, ejecuta el siguiente comando asegurándote de poner el nombre de la distribución que quieres desinstalar:

```
wsl --unregister NombreDistro
```

[Referencia](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/faq#how-do-i-uninstall-a-wsl-distribution-) (en inglés)

Comment: La respuesta no es adecuada. Se pide como desinstalar un aplicativo binario ejecutable, y se responde que borre la distribución.

Comment: @gilito, cierto, esa opción no era parte de la pregunta, pero sí de un comentario.

Comment: igualmente tu respuesta enriqueze al entorno de la pregunta. Gracias!!!!